# TinyMCE is modifying the XHTML 1.0 Strict HTML I input. How can I stop it?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, tinymce, xhtml-1.0-strict

The code I want to have saved through TinyMCE is as follows:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="550" height="90" id="homepage-banner">
    <param name="movie" value="/images/header.swf" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/images/header.swf" width="550" height="90">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
            <img src="/images/header.jpg" width="550" height="90" alt="" border="0" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Sadly, what I end up with is:

```
<object data="/images/header.swf" height="90" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550">
    <param name="id" value="homepage-banner" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />                
    <param name="src" value="/images/header.swf" />               
</object>
```

The purpose of the stripped parts of the code is to provide a fallback image if flash is not available on the client.

In my `tinyMCE.init({ ... });` I am using `verify_html: true` and `valid_elements` is set as per [this forum topic](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=27) whereby all valid XHTML 1.0 Strict elements are allowed. I have checked and the above code does comply with the XHTML 1.0 Strict standard.

I have tried just setting `verify_html` to false but it had no effect. **How can TinyMCE be configured to leave my HTML alone?!**

Comment: Where does the `<object>` HTML come from? From a plugin/dialog window or is it already in the HTML?

Comment: It's just a standard block of HTML I have and use to insert a flash video with a fallback image. I go to HTML view in TinyMCE and paste it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using [SWF Object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) from google code.

I now paste the following code into TinyMCE:

```
<div id="header-image">
    <img border="0" src="/images/header.jpg" width="550" height="90"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("/images/header.swf", "header-image", "550", "90", "9.0.0");</script>
</div>
```

With the following code in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject2.js"></script>
```